# Is Evelyn viable somewhere else than in the jungle?

Tags: league-of-legends

I main Eve jungle, and I play her ad bruiser.

I was thinking about bringing Eve to the **top lane in a Ad Bruiser style**, or  in **mid lane in a Ap-Assassin style**.

Would it be viable? In what sitation would it work best, and especially *how* to play her in lane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to her nerfs/changes, i would say no. You can play her Top/Mid, but there will always be better options. Her damage output is not that great on AP anymore. As a toplaner, she will always be beaten by other common toplaner like Riven, Renekton or Jax.

In a specific teamcomp you can play her mid, shove the lane and roam. That might work in a coordinated team. But in SoloQ, she isn't viable elsewhere.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking! If I would play it somewhere else, it would be Top lane, but even then she'll get wrecked.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although the answer might be sufficient enough, I would like some more explanations about why she may (is) not viable top/mid?

Comment: As for mid lane, you're VERY susceptible to getting poked down, even more so while Xerath, Syndra and the like are popular. As for top, no inherent sustain, no CC until 6 (it's hard to gank for you), and I feel that you'd probably lose out on trades with your Q's that do less damage than your opponents autos.

Answer (score 2):

The strength for eve are invisible ganking and high mobility, hence she's still a good jungler, but a terrible laner. If you really want to play her in lane, mid-lane is a better option in my opinion, because you can still abuse her strength through roaming. As for top-lane, as far as I know, she can hardly beat any top-laner 1v1.

In terms of roam heavy mid-laner, there are many better options in this category(twisted fate, leblanc,kassadin, etc). You are gonna have some hard time farming in early game because 90% of mid-laner can shit on you early game, and this percent might be even higher in top-lane. Once you get some levels, try to push as much as possible, and start roaming, abuse your invisible ganking, you will still be relevant in the game if you can gain some early game lead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't listen to them.

Eve mid was good before she got relegated to the jungle, and she's still good against skill shot heavy champs.

Eve mid has great ganking potential. You can even gank your own lane.

Rush sheen, then haunting guise. When you finish the lich bane you can nearly 1 shot squishes.

Especially now that pink wards are at a premium. You basically shut down the enemy support.